# $(this).next('input').focus(); not working inside and form

Tags: jquery, html, focus

I'm trying to force the enter key to act as a tab key.

I was following this jsFiddle [Click here for JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnEB5/3/)

This if my html.

```
<form name='form' method='post'>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='form-group row'>
        <label class='col-sm-4 control-label text-primary' for='nickname'>First Name:</label>
        <div class='col-sm-8'>
            <input id='nickname' type='text' name='txtfname' class='input-enter form-control'/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id='div_name' class='form-group row'>
        <label class='col-sm-4 control-label text-primary' for='nickname'>Last Name:</label>
        <div class='col-sm-8'>
            <input id='nickname' type='text' name='txtlname' class='input-enter form-control'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

This is my jquery codes. Jquery version 3.1.1.

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
    // $(this).next('input').focus();
    // $(this).parent().next().find('.input-enter').focus();  
    $(this).closest('.input-enter').find('input').focus();
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Enter key has been pressed!");
}
});
```

Update: the alert box pops up when i hit the Enter key.
Second update.

Full html codes. Dont worry about the id being multiple. ijust copied and pasted.

```
<form name='form' method='post'>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='form-group row'>
        <label class='col-sm-4 control-label text-primary' for='nickname'>First Name:</label>
        <div class='col-sm-8'>
            <input id='nickname' type='text' name='txtfname' class='input-enter form-control'/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='div_name' class='form-group row'>
        <label class='col-sm-4 control-label text-primary' for='nickname'>L:</label>
        <div class='col-sm-8'>
            <input id='nickname' type='text' name='txtlname' class='input-enter form-control'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='form-group row'>
        <label class='col-sm-4 control-label text-primary' for='nickname'>First Name:</label>
        <div class='col-sm-8'>
            <input id='nickname' type='text' name='txtfname' class='input-enter form-control'/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='div_name' class='form-group row'>
        <label class='col-sm-4 control-label text-primary' for='nickname'>L:</label>
        <div class='col-sm-8'>
            <input id='nickname' type='text' name='txtlname' class='input-enter form-control'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: `closest()` operates by finding a match on the element, and its *parents*.  It does not look like your input elements have a parent that has the class `input-enter'.

Comment: @Taplar I update my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change

```
$(this).closest('.input-enter').find('input').focus();
```

to

```
$(this).closest('.row').nextAll(':has(.input-enter):first').find('.input-enter').focus();
```

Also you should fix your input id attribute because its double ('nickname' is used twice which is invalid). Now 'enter' works like 'tab' 
 - here is [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6pns9e9d/)

**After Question UPDATE**

Use this code:

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {

    let focusable = $('form').find('input')
    let next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this)+1);
    if (next.length) {
      next.focus();
    } else {
            // form.submit();
    }
    return false;
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

And here is [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6pns9e9d/2/).

Comment: Why do this?  What is the problem?  Also what if there are multiple rows with multiple `input-enter`?  Assume the OP doesn't understand what the issue is, :)

Comment: @Taplar, I do have many many inputs which i need to be focusable with the enter key. the class input-enter is strictly for that purpose

Comment: @kamil i have many inputs boxed your solution is only for a 2 input textbox.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Thanks for helping. your code works But I think it is my fault  that i did not include the whole html . I have two columns of boxes using bootstrap grid system. Your code only work for the first column(Left) it will not continue focusing boxes on the second column (right).

Comment: @wilson382 i Update answer

Comment: kindly mark my question as solved. Thanks @Kamil kielczewski